# Generate client certificate to service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-service-fabric, client-certificates

According to this tutorial [Create a Service Fabric cluster by using Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm) , I created the server Self-Signed .pfx certificate.After that I enter certificate thumbprint,SourceVault,CertificateURL to azure portal.

What should I do to **get** client certificate,to enter its thumbprint to azure portal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you generated the client cert you should have generated the thumbprint at that point. If not then you should be able to install that cert locally on your machine (If it's not already) and using MMC go into the properties and find the thumbprint there to copy and paste, keep in mind it needs to have all spaces removed.

Answer (score -1):

Did you uplooad the certificate to the keyvault?

```
 Invoke-AddCertToKeyVault -SubscriptionId <guid> -ResourceGroupName westus-mykeyvault -Location "West US" -VaultName mywestusvault -CertificateName mycert -Password "<password>" -UseExistingCertificate -ExistingPfxFilePath "C:\path\to\mycertkey.pfx"
```

After that - you'll be able to fetch the thumbprint as specified in the guide.

```
Name  : CertificateThumbprint
Value : E21DBC64B183B5BF355C34C46E03409FEEAEF58D

Name  : SourceVault
Value : /subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/westus-mykeyvault/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/mywestusvault
```

Make sure to follow all the steps in the guide you listed and you should have your inputs.

Comment: The answer is totally incorrect, I wrote that II enter certificate thumbprint,SourceVault,CertificateURL to azure portal.I'm interested in client certificates

Comment: @cosset no it's correct. Upload cert to kv by following instruction above then add client cert thumbprint as above

Comment: @Mardoxx,the question is where I can find client certificate thumbprint,how can I obtain client certificate.At this answer I only see server certificate thumbprint,I know how to get it.The problem with client certificate

Comment: You mean how to add client cert via arm template? Have a look at the samples on github or look at the schemas